# Does Lua have an NLP tool with the capabilities of the NLTK?

Tags: lua, nlp, nltk

The NLTK is a powerful NLP tool with much documentation, but most of my projects use Lua, not Python. Is there a Lua equivalent of the NLTK that uses native Lua code?

Comment: What about using lunatic-python to access `nltk` from lua?

Comment: Does that require using Python code inside Lua code?

Comment: yes because lua code is going to be calling python code. How else will you use python libraries in lua without porting stuff over?

Comment: lua torch comes with an NPL libraries: https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet#natural-language-processing

Comment: I had a similar issue, so I recently created https://github.com/pncnmnp/LuaNLP which is an NLP toolkit and contains support for many of the common tasks seen in NLTK.